# Add Custom Claims to Service Account Via Identity Platform GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, service-accounts

Context: I have an API that is based on id token authentication (via Oauth2 flow). Tokens are transferred as bearer token in the auth header. The backend then authenticates the users and pulls the custom claims (I add permissions to custom claims on users using another service).
Currently I only have a fronend that consumes the API though I also need to plug in a backend service that talks to the API.

I thought a good solution would be to use a [service accounts for impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions) and attach custom claims to the service account like one does [with users](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-configure-custom-claims). One can definitely create ID Connect Tokens like documented here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#generate-tokens

**Though, how would I add custom claims to that id connect token generated from a service account?**

Comment: AFAIK, there is no custom claim possible in the client libraries. However, if you build yourself the JWT and ask the service account credential API to sign  your token, it should work.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I realised that Firebase auth is not working like the IdentityProvider does.. despite being plugged into it. I will update my question. Though would you know how I would do it using firebase auth?